# Merge two csv columns in powershell, order of columns

Tags: powershell, csv

I am currently using the code below that I found on here to concat 2 columns into a new column. The problem is that when I export the csv, the columns are not in the order that I list below. How can I sort the columns into the order I want?

Thanks

```
$objs =@();
$output = Import-csv -Path C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\External_ID_Test.csv | ForEach { 
    $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
        Employee_ID      = $_.Employye_ID
        Base_Cost_Center = $_.Base_Cost_Center
        Entity           = $_.Entity    
        ExternalID       = [String]::Concat($_.Entity,$_.Base_Cost_Center)  
    }   
    $objs += $Object;
} 
$objs 
$objs | Export-CSv C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Export_External_ID_Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `[ordered]`?  `New-Object PSObject -Property [ordered] @{ `
Hashtables are not ordered by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your are assigning the output of the `ForEach-Object` to the variable `$Output` but aren't outputting anything.

Simplify your script by using an ordered `[PSCustomObject]` and avoiding the `+=` which will rebuild the array `$objs` on every iteration.

```
$output = Import-csv -Path C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\External_ID_Test.csv | ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject]{            
        Employee_ID      = $_.Employye_ID
        Base_Cost_Center = $_.Base_Cost_Center
        Entity           = $_.Entity    
        ExternalID       = [String]::Concat($_.Entity,$_.Base_Cost_Center)  
    }   
} 
$output
$output | Export-CSv C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Export_External_ID_Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this, I am very new to powershell and I am just trying to solve a specific issue.

Comment: When I run this, the output file looks like this, "Attributes","File","IsFilter","IsConfiguration","Module","StartPosition","DebuggerHidden","Ast"
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Attribute]",,"False","False",,"System.Management.Automation.PSToken","False","{            
        Employee_ID      = $_.Employye_ID
        Base_Cost_Center = $_.Base_Cost_Center
        Entity           = $_.Entity    
        ExternalID       = [String]::Concat($_.Entity,$_.Base_Cost_Center)  
    }"

Comment: is there something else I need in the script to run this?

Comment: That doesn't match the properties you have shown. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54812635/edit) your question to contain some sample/neutralized lines from your .csv file.